# Does Untaidake, the Cloud Keeper now provide mana for casting Planeswalkers?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With Planeswalkers being Legendary now, and all Planeswalkers receiving errata to become Legendary, does **[Untaidake, the Cloud Keeper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUntaidake%2c%20the%20Cloud%20Keeper%5d)** generate {C}{C} mana for the purpose of summoning Planeswalkers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Planeswalkers are legendary.  Untaidake, the Cloud Keeper gives mana for Legendary purposes.

Comment: Thank you! That's going to be interesting sideboard for Eldrazi Tron

Comment: @ApostolApostolov that is an interesting way to look at it. Maybe in a match up where planeswalkers would be more important than the Eldrazi, you could replace 1 or 2 temples with them. That being said, Untaidake is a legendary land, so you would only want a few more than likely.